# Group actions and orbits

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, group-actions

Let $X=\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\}\}$ and $G=S_4$

(a) Show that $\phi \{x_1,x_2\}=\{\phi (x_1),\phi (x_2)\}$ determines an action of $S_4$ on $X$, where $\phi \in G$

(b) Determine the number of orbits of this action.

(a) I’m not really sure how to explain this but it comes as an intuitive action that if you act $\phi$ on $x_1$, it is just mapping $x_1$ to $\phi (x_1)$, which essentially is just mapping 1 to $\phi (1)$. But I’m not sure how to present this formally.

(b) Any hints on how I can do this? I’m not sure if I should write out all 24 elements in $S_4$ and use Burnside’s Theorem to find the number of orbits. But if I do so it might be too tedious. What happens when the it becomes larger? i.e $S_5$ acting on $X$; I don’t think I can write out all 120 elements.

Wondering if anyone can help with this?

Comment: What are $x_1$ and $x_2$ denoting? I guess they range over $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: @Berci Yes. OP is acting on a graph.

Comment: If we take $g=(1,2) \in S_4$ then $g$ reverses the co-ordinates of each member of $X$ (I am assuming that the members of $X$ are ordered tuples rather than unordered sets). But $\{2,1\}, \{3,1\}$ etc, are not in $X$. So I am puzzled as to how the operation specified is an action on $X$ if $X$ only consists of the six points listed. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @gandalf61 Yes it’s supposed to be an unordered set

Comment: @Icycarus But in that case each member of $G$ simply maps each member of $X$ to itself, so this is a very uninteresting action ! Is it possible that the operation that is intended is $\phi\{x_1,x_2\} = \{\phi(x_1), \phi(x_2)\}$ ?

Comment: @gandalf61 Hi yes. I just checked with my lecturer again and it is indeed what you have claimed. In that scenario, how should I explain it formally?(Though it seems very straightforward)

Comment: I have edited the question too

Comment: @gandalf61: for e.g. $\phi=(2\, 3)$, we get $\phi\{1,2\}=\{1, 3\}$, so the action on $X$ is not trivial.

Comment: @Berci yes, with the new edited version the action is not trivial. But before the edit, when I wrote my comment, the action was $\phi\{x_1,x_2\}=\{x_{\phi(1)},x_{\phi(2)}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

a) Note that $X$ contains *all* 2 elements subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$, so $X$ is indeed closed under the given map and that map satisfies the condition of being a group action.

b) Start with an element of $X$ and find *its* orbit. If there's any element left off, find its orbit too, and so on..

Answer (score 1):

a) To formally show that $\phi\{x_1,x_2\}=\{\phi(x_1),\phi(x_2)\}$ is an action, you need to show two things:

1) $e\{x_1,x_2\}=\{x_1,x_2\} \space \forall \{x_1,x_2\} \in X$ where $e$ is the identity in $G$.

2) $\phi_1(\phi_2\{x_1,x_2\}) = (\phi_1 \phi_2)\{x_1,x_2\} \space \forall \{x_1,x_2\} \in X \space \forall \phi_1, \phi_2 \in G$

These are both straightforward.

b) Given two elements of $X$, think about how you can find a member of $G$ that maps one to the other (in fact, there is more than one as user25959 hints at above). This shows that $G$ acts *transitively* on $X$, so there is only one orbit.

Comment: i) the identity element is (1)(2)(3)(4) so applying $e\{x_1,x_2\}=\{x_1,x_2\}$ so it’s straightforward. How about (ii)? How do we go about showing it?

Comment: @Icycarus For (ii) here is an example. To find a permutation in $g \in G$ that maps $\{1.2\}$ to $\{3,4\}$, you could start by requiring $g$ to map $1$ to $3$ and $2$ to $4$. Now $3$ can either map to $1$, which gives $g=(13)(24)$, or $3$ can map to $2$ which gives $g=(1324)$. Note that $3$ cannot map to $4$ because $2$ already maps to $4$. Alternatively, you can require $g$ to map $1$ to $4$ and $2$ to $3$, which gives $g=(14)(23)$ or $g=(1423)$. So there are four possibilities for $g$.

Answer (score 0):

The stabilizer of $\{i,j\}$ consists of the permutations $e, (ij), (kl)$, and $(ij)(kl)$ where $k,l$ are the "other two" elements of $\{1,2,3,4\}$. So by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, $|Orb_{\{i,j\}}|\cdot 4 = |S_4|= 24$.